# Decrypt the content of a signed CMS_ContentInfo*

Tags: c, openssl, libcrypto

I am having problems accessing the `EnvelopedData` within a signed `CMS_ContentInfo*` object when using a memory `BIO`.

Using the following code, everything works fine :

```
BIO* output = BIO_new_file("/absolute/path/test.txt", "r+");
                    if (CMS_verify(cms, stack, store, dcont, output, CMS_NOINTERN)) {
    BIO_flush(output);
    BIO_reset(output);
    CMS_ContentInfo* cms2 = SMIME_read_CMS(output, nullptr);
}
```

cms2 is instantiated properly and I am able to decrypt its content. Although, I don't want the file to be written to disk so I am trying to make this work in memory like so :

```
BIO* output = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
if (CMS_verify(cms, stack, store, dcont, output, CMS_NOINTERN)) {
    BIO_flush(output);
    BIO_seek(output, 0);
    CMS_ContentInfo* cms2 = SMIME_read_CMS(output, nullptr);
}
```

For some reason, it seems the `SMIME_read_CMS` function can never read from the `BIO`. Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my solution. Here is the piece of code I have used :

```
BIO* output = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
if (CMS_verify(cms, stack, store, dcont, nullptr, CMS_NOINTERN)) {
    CMS_ContentInfo* cms2 = SMIME_read_CMS(dcont, nullptr);
}
```

Apparently, it is the dcont `BIO` that holds the `SignedData` and I can properly decrypt it afterwards using the `cms2` variable.